# Simple javascript 'new' keyword

Tags: javascript, object, new-operator

I created simple object

```
var myobject={

  sum:function(){
    console.log('sum')
  },
  sub:function(){
    console.log('sub')
  }
}
```

then i created new object from the above object like:-

```
var newmyobject=new Object(myobject);
```

Finally i added a property to new object like:-

```
newmyobject.mult=function(){
  console.log('multi');
}
```

Now problem is that when i do

```
console.log(myobject);
console.log(newmyobject);
```

Both are showing same result. I was expecting "mult()" should only be in newmyobject.

Comment: Objects are passed by reference. You'll have to clone it to add unique methods.

Comment: @JayBhatt really worthy comment to be an answer :)

Comment: @NullPoiиteя Agree. But `@elclanrs` has already given a good answer.

Comment: Then 'new' is just providing the reference but that can be achieve by simple '=' operator.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`new Object(obj)` doesn't create a copy, it simply returns `obj` as an object, and it already is an object. You can do:

```
var newmyobject = Object.create(myobject)
newmyobject.mult = function() {
  console.log('multi');
}

myobject.isPrototypeOf(newmyobject) // true
```

Now `newmyobject` will inherit `sub` and `sum` from `myobject`, and `mult` will be an own property.

The use for `new` is for constructor functions, for example:

```
function MyObject() {}
MyObject.prototype.sum = function(){}
MyObject.prototype.sub = function(){}

var obj = new MyObject
obj.mult = function(){}

obj instanceof MyObject // true
```

Comment: Yes great but one doubt in my mind then what is the use of 'new' i can simply use var  newmyobject=myobject instead.

Comment: `new` is for use with constructor functions, see if the edit helps. `newmyobject=myobject` is the same exact object, while `Object.create` gives you a new object, with another object as prototype.